# reduce() to produce an object of objects

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an new object from another object using reduce()

```js
const FontFamilyMap = {
    SansSerif: {
        fontFamily: 'arial, helvetica, sans-serif'
    },
    Serif: {
        fontFamily: '"times new roman"'
    }
};

const test = Object.keys(FontFamilyMap).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur] = {style: {fontFamily: FontFamilyMap[cur].fontFamily}};
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(test);
```

this is almost working but the ouput is missing the inner object to the `style` object `{fontFamily: FontFamilyMap[cur].fontFamily}` see [codepen](https://codepen.io/sandra-willford/pen/mQpQMR?editors=0012)

the expected output should look something like this...

`SansSerif: {style: {fontFamily: 'arial, helvetica, sans-serif'}}`

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz added

Comment: *"see codepen"* No, instead ensure your whole question (including any necessary code) is **in** your question, not just linked. (I think you *did* include all the code; I wrapped it in a snippet for you, but it doesn't have the problem you describe.) Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put the [mcve] **in** the question using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: I certainly can't see any reason from the code above that the objects would be missing the object on the `style` property.

Comment: please add what the reducing is for. actually, you generate the same as before, just with style property. (which works!)

Comment: Your expected output is exactly what you are getting in codepen link

Comment: It seems to work the way you expect it to work. Check again:)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, right.

Comment: The output of the code is the same as the format expected by the OP. what IS the question here?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't the required output? `const test = { style: FontFamilyMap }`

Comment: testing in my actual code. when check the value of test in the codepen console it does not output right.

Comment: this works in my actual code... @T.J.Crowder now i see why you discourage external links :)

Comment: maybe it's the funky output. you could use `console.log(JSON.stringify(test, null, 4));` and see the wanted result.

Comment: btw, a short approach is to use the entries and assign the object. `Object
            .entries(FontFamilyMap)
            .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => Object.assign(acc, { [k]: { style: v } }), {});`

Comment: @NinaScholz you may post as an answer.

Comment: @SandraWillford - :-) Well, it's not so much *me* who discourages it, it's SO itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, codepaen does not show the complete object and takes an abbreviation with just showing `Object`.

To overcome this, you could take [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and get the formatted object with

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(test, null, 4));
```

This approach may not show function or other objects like Maps or Sets or other data structures .

---

You could use your code with some minor changes:

- use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) for getting key/value pairs,
- use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and get an object with assigned properties with
- an object with a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and
- a [short hand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
const
    FontFamilyMap = { SansSerif: { fontFamily: 'arial, helvetica, sans-serif' }, Serif: { fontFamily: '"times new roman"' } },
    test = Object
        .entries(FontFamilyMap)
        .reduce((acc, [key, style]) => Object.assign(acc, { [key]: { style } }), {});

console.log(test);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```